# Off-policy form of control variate, from RL Barto Sutton

Tags: reinforcement-learning

In the [Reinforcement Learning book by Sutton & Barto, version 2018](http://incompleteideas.net/book/RLbook2018.pdf), authors provided a formula (Eq. 7.14, page 151) of the off-policy form with control variate :
[image]

How can I understand this equation? I can understand if we are on-policy, the later two terms inside the gamma part cancels out. But anyone why do we have to multiply the rho with G_{t+1:h}? How does this formula make any sense?

Comment: I would add the formula in the question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this not a programming question as defined in the [help]. It would probably be more suited to [stats.se].

Comment: The equation essentially comes from the section 4 of the paper http://auai.org/uai2018/proceedings/papers/282.pdf. It leverages the variance reduction technique control variate, with random variable Y being \rhoQ(S_{t+1},A_{t+1}) and its expectation knownas \bar{V}(S_{t+1}) and the coefficient c being -1.

Answer (score 0):

The \rho_{t+1} should always be there, even without control variate. This is because this equation concerns state-action values. It becomes clearer when you write out the arguments of the returns:
[image]
where [image], with pi and b the target and behavior policies respectively, and A_{t+1} was sampled according to the behavior policy.

The book in this section 7.4 is a bit confusing, because it goes straight from on-policy to off-policy with covariates, skipping over the recursive expressions of the returns for off-policy without covariates.